# Create model with containing CellList using GWT Editor Framework?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, gwtp, gwt-editors

I have the following model:

```
class Book {
  String title;
  // getter and setter
}

class Author {
  private name;
  private List<Book> books;
  // getter and setter  
}
```

I want to create a GWT Widget where I can create an author and create as many books as possible while creating the author in the same view. Here is how it might look like:

[image]

You can add as many books as you want:

[image]

I want to use the GWT Editor framework to populate the data between the view and the models. Here is how I do it only for the `Author` model without the list.

My UiBinder:

```
<g:TextBox ui:field="nameInput"/>
```

My Widget.java:

```
public class MyWidgetView {

  @Path(value="name")
  @UiField
  TextBox nameInput;

public interface EditorDriver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Author, MyWidgetView> { }

  @Override
  public SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Author, ?> createEditorDriver() {
    EditorDriver driver = GWT.create(EditorDriver.class);
    driver.initialize(this);
    return driver;
  }

}
```

In my presenter I created:

```
SimpleBeanEditorDriver<TriggerDto, ?> editorDriver = getView().createEditorDriver();
```

This works fine for a simple model but I want to use it for the above author model which contains a `List<Book>`.

**How do I have to setup the UiBinder such that I can add Books to the author and what do I have to do with the editor to get the created list of `Book`s flushed into the author model?**

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can achieve that. You'll need to create an Editor, a ListEditor and an EditorSource

```
public class BooksEditor implements IsWidget, IsEditor<ListEditor<Book, BookEditor>> {
    private final HTMLPanel main;
    private final ListEditor<Book, BookEditor>> editor;

    @Inject
    BooksEditor(
            Provider<BookEditor> bookEditorProvider) {
        main = new HTMLPanel("");
        editor = ListEditor.of(new BookEditorSource(bookEditorProvider, main));
    }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<Book, BookEditor> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        return main;
    }`
}

public class BookEditorSource extends EditorSource<BookEditor> {
    private final Provider<BookEditor> bookEditorProvider;
    private final HTMLPanel books;

    public BookEditorSource(
            Provider<BookEditor> bookEditorProvider,
            HTMLPanel books) {
        this.bookEditorProvider = bookEditorProvider;
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public BookEditor create(int index) {
        BookEditor bookEditor = bookEditorProvider.get();
        books.add(bookEditor);

        return bookEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(BookEditor subEditor) {
        super.dispose(subEditor);

        books.remove(subEditor);
    }
}
```

To create the BookEditor class, simply create a new Widget that implements `Editor<Book>` and create the according UiFields to be able to edit your Book object. The values will be handled by the parent Author SimpleBeanDriver.
Then in your `MyWidgetView`, simply add a UiField :

```
@UiField(provided = true)
@Path("books")
BooksEditor booksInput;
```

If you want to add/remove widgets on the fly and synchronize it with the ListEditor, simply work with the BooksEditor class. `editor.getList().add(new Book())` will automatically add a new BookEditor in your panel. Calling `editor.getList().remove(bookToRemove)` will remove it (see the dispose() method in BookEditorSource, it's called when calling remove on the list).

Comment: What is the difference between BookEditor and BooksEditor is this a spelling error?

Comment: The List<Book> should be represented by a CellList. Could you please update your answer to make it work.

Comment: Regarding the difference between BooksEditor and BookEditor, BooksEditor edits a List of Book, while BookEditor edits a single book

Comment: As for the CellList, it's a totally different question/answer. It requires the use of HasDataEditor adapter instead. I suggest you look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/4sqfLGKVH9o if you want to use a CellList instead of a simple HTMLPanel and your own widgets. I believe the solution posted above gives you more control than a CellList

Comment: But I need to use a cellList. So could you please update your answer?